# how to update the table each time that button clicked

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of items and I want to show them in a table and I have a button and whenever a user click on that the array would be updated and the table should update after that.

Here is a codes link of my code  :

[link to code](http://plnkr.co/edit/V90cMRB1sDl5U5xPYuFH?p=preview)

here is my code as well:

```
 var app=angular.module('app',[]);
 app.controller('table',function($scope){
 alert("ddd");
 $scope.typesHash=[{name : 'sugar', price : 1,unit:1 },
                {name : 'lemon', price : 100,unit:2.5 }];
   $scope.addTable=function(){
    var arr={name : 'meat', price : 200,unit:3.3  };
      $scope.typesHash.add(arr);
  }
});
```

When the code loads for the first time table gets updated but when I click on the button nothing happens!!!
Can anyone help how I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually call the function clickTable, your expression was incorrect. AND you need to remove the extra controller:

```
   <div id="clcikbtn" style="background-color:black;width:20px;height:20px;" ng-click="addTable" ng-controller="table"></div>
```

Should be:

```
   <div id="clcikbtn" style="background-color:black;width:20px;height:20px;" ng-click="addTable()"></div>
```

Finally, change 'add' to 'push' in addTable function:

```
      $scope.typesHash.push(arr);
```

Updated plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/un81F5wpnvHr6zNtlFzL?p=preview